# Attachment is not working in SharePoint server edition

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, attachments, vuejs

Attachment is not working in SharePoint server edition, which was working fine in SharePoint 2016. we have used Vue.js in our custom form, rest of functionalities works fine as expected but attachment is not working. please find the below code and error I'm getting for attachment section.

Error Message:

> 500 (Internal Server Error)

Code:

```
var ListRepo = new ListName();

vm.ListObj.AttachmentFiles.results.forEach(function (attachment) {
                    if (!attachment.isUploaded) {
                                 alert(attachment);
                        promises.push(ListRepo.addAttachment(vm.ListObj.Id, attachment.data, attachment.FileName).then(function (file) {
                            //nothing to do here
                        }, function (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                            throw err;
                        }));
                    }
                });


                Promise.all(promises).then(function (result) {
                    if (moveToNextPhase) {
                        window.location.href = url;
                    } else {
                        if (vm.ReferencesValueP || vm.workRedirect) {
                            window.location.href = window.location.toString();
                        }
                        $.unblockUI();
                    }
                }, function (err) {                                    
                    //if it's a timeout, chances are the calls are going to succeed...
                    if (err.statusText === "timeout") {
                        if (moveToNextPhase) {
                            window.location.href = url;
                        } 
                        else {
                            vm.message = " Error saving .  Please contact your administrator Submit.";
                            alert(vm.message);
                            setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = window.location.toString(); }, 5000).then(function () {
                            }, function (err) {
                                vm.message = "Error saving .  Please contact your administrator.";
                                $.unblockUI();

 

                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        vm.message =err.statusText;
                        vm.message =  Error saving .  Please contact your administrator.";
                        alert(vm.message);
                        setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = window.location.toString(); }, 5000).then(function () {

 

 

                        }, function (err) {
                            vm.message = "Error saving .  Please contact your administrator.";
                            $.unblockUI();

 

                        });

                    }
                });
```

Thanks in advance.